# Tailwind CSS v3.1 Arbitrary Variants Not Applying to Custom Class (bq-panel) – Unable to Set Width

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I'm currently facing challenges with Tailwind CSS v3.1 arbitrary variants not being applied as expected to a custom Angular dropdown component named *app-drop-down*. The primary concern revolves around setting a fixed width of 160px for the dropdown panel *(bq-panel)*.

Note that ***bq-panel*** is a part of a third-party library used under the hood to display the dropdown panel.

I have tried different variations of the format, such as `[&_bq-panel]:width-40`, `[&_#bq-panel]:width-40`, and several others. Strangely, when I tested the arbitrary variants on other elements, such as paragraph, it worked as expected.

I'm thinking the problem might be because the `'bq-panel'` is utilized **internally** by the library and isn't part of the actual code. This could be why the styling isn't applying correctly to the panel, unlike paragraph, which is directly in the code."

***app.component.html***

```
<app-drop-down [options]="(options$ | async) ?? []" [dropdownName]="currentEmployee.name" (itemSelect)="onLogout()" class="[&_bq-panel]:w-40"> <!-- ... (other dropdown content) ... --> </app-drop-down>
```

***drop-down.component.html***

```
    <div class="mt-xxl3 place-items-center gap-m">
  <bq-dropdown
    distance="4"
    placement="bottom-end"
    open=""
    panel-height=""
    skidding="0"
    strategy="fixed"
    [class]="dropdownWidth + ' hydrated'"
    sameWidth="false"
  >
    <bq-button
      appearance="text"
      block="true"
      [size]="buttonSize"
      type="button"
      variant="standard"
      slot="trigger"
      justify-content="center"
      class="hydrated"
    >
      <ng-container *ngIf="iconTrigger; else textContent">
        <ng-content select="[icon]"></ng-content>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-template #textContent>
        <div class="flex w-40 justify-evenly">
          <div class="flex">
            <ng-content select="[image]"></ng-content>
          </div>
          <span *ngIf="dropdownName" class="flex items-center"
            >{{ dropdownName }}
            <ng-content select="[caret]"></ng-content>
          </span>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </bq-button>

    <div>
      <bq-option-list aria-label="Options" class="hydrated" role="listbox">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let option of options">
          <bq-option [value]="option" class="hydrated" (click)="itemSelected()">
            <p>{{ option }}</p>
          </bq-option>
        </ng-container>
      </bq-option-list>
    </div>
  </bq-dropdown>
</div>
```

Here is how the element looks like the DOM:

```
<div class="bq-panel" aria-hidden="false" part="panel" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate(887px, 68px); visibility: visible;"><slot></slot></div>
```

Comment: If I understood this correctly, you want to apply some Tailwind class to `<div class="bq-panel" ...>` element, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Based on this understanding, I have proposed a solution in the Answers section, if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you made typos in both attempts at constructing the correct class name. The target element seems to have a **class** of `bq-panel`, so the CSS selector would be `.bq-panel`, not `bq-panel` or `#bq-panel`.

Furthermore, in Tailwind, the CSS class names that apply the `width` CSS property are prefixed by `w-`, not `width-`. So to apply `width: 10rem` (equivalent to `160px` at `16px` root font size), the class name would be `w-40`.

Thus, to put this all together, the class name you may be after is `[&_.bq-panel]:w-40`.

Comment: Correction: In the code itself, I did apply "w-", and not "width-". I changed the class name to "[&_.bq-panel]:w-40", still not working. Note that it's "bq-panel" and not "bg-panel".

Comment: I'm aware it is `bq-panel` not `bg-panel`. You said "I have tried different variations of the format, such as `[&_bq-panel]:width-40`, `[&_#bq-panel]:width-40` […]", thus there seems to be some contradictions, so I wanted to clarify this. Furthermore, consider checking: the code is covered by the `content` file globs, whether any other CSS may be interfering that prevents the `width` value from applying how you'd expect, a Tailwind compilation has run since you added the class, the `width` core Tailwind plugin has not been disabled, `40` is a valid `width` value`.

Comment: The change simply doesn't seem to have an effect. I tried applying something else, like `class="[&_p]:bg-red-500"`, and there is no issue.

Comment: Consider checking: the code is covered by the `content` file globs, whether any other CSS may be interfering that prevents the `width` value from applying how you'd expect, a Tailwind compilation has run since you added the class, the `width` core Tailwind plugin has not been disabled and that `40` is a valid width value.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.css` file (or whatever you have called it), probably where you have imported `@tailwind base;`, etc. imports, you may want to try this

```css
.bq-panel {
  @apply w-40;
}
```

For more details, you can refer https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply.

> This is useful when you need to write custom CSS (like to override the styles in a third-party library) but still want to work with your design tokens and use the same syntax you’re used to using in your HTML.

Comment: No success. I have also tried applying like the following, but still not luck:
"width: 160px !important;". Note: I am using SCSS.

Comment: Is the `width` property with `160px` value (or the class `w-40`) visible in dev tools styles? It could be possible that the style is there, but not actually applied because of any reason. Or maybe you are applying the styles where it won't work and needs to be applied somewhere else.

Comment: The change is not visible in the console. I tried applying `w-40`. Regarding applying the style to the wrong element: If I directly apply the width in the style of the element in the console, it works without a problem: `.bq-panel {width: 160px;}`

Comment: Can you try styling some other element, probably one of your own elements in HTML, in the same SCSS file to be sure if that file is being read correctly? There could be many possibilities what could have gone wrong.

Comment: I tried styling the `<p>`, since I have it used in the custom component and it works without any problem whatsoever. Could it be due to `bq-panel` not being available in the source code only in the DOM?

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem, I guess, because I had a similar issue where an element rendered by a 3rd-party library was required to be styled using Tailwind CSS. It worked with the above solution. It was a Vue project setup using Vite with no CSS pre-processors. Tailwind CSS was setup following the official documentation for Vite.